# border around text input in a html form

Tags: html, css

I want a red border around my input text fields in a html form. But using css

```
input { border: 1px solid #d66 }
```

also puts a red border around my buttons (which I don't want).

input.button, input.submit or input.text and anything inside { } doesn't do anything.

How do I change the border around a text input only, and how do I change the font in the submit button only? I'm using IE9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To target textboxes, use

```
input[type="text"] { border: 1px solid #d66 }
```

There are a lot more attribute selectors available.

Have a look at http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 4):

What you need is an attribute selector:

```
input[type="text"] { border: 1px solid #d66 }
```

This selects the input of type "text."

You can also use other attribute selectors to select other elements:

```
input[type="submit"] { border: 1px solid #d66 }
input[type="checkbox"] { border: 1px solid #d66 }
```

But also be aware that these selectors are not supported by IE7 and lower.